# How memchr in C actually works?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, string.h

I am little confused about the working technique of `memchr()` in `C` . I have observed different implementation of `memchr()` and found that first it takes and converts the character or number to `unsigned char` type and then searches a array byte by byte.

I have two questions:

1.If it converts the anything to `unsigned char` then how it compares a number which has size bigger than  `unsigned char`, for example `int` type.
2.If it compares byte by byte and returns then returns the address of the first occurence of the character, then suppose I want to search `0x8` in a array.

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  const int arr[5] = {0x1021, 0x8988, 0x706, 0x50, 0x22};
  int * ptr;

  ptr = memchr(arr, 0x89, sizeof(arr));
  printf("arr:%p ptr:%p\n", arr, ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

It should return the address of the 3rd byte of the array as the `0x89` matches with first byte of the element `0x8988` of the array which is at 7th byte as `memchr()` matches byte by byte `(unsigned char)` not `int` type.

Assuming: `int` is 4 bytes and `unsigned char` is 1 byte.

Comment: Generally speaking, attempting to use `memchr` on an array of any other type will not be portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It doesn't.  `memchr` can only search for values that are representable by `unsigned char`.
2. If you supply an array of `int`s as the first argument to `memchr`, then it will look for the `unsigned char` value you supplied as the second argument, within the *object representation* of each `int`.

   The object representation of any type T other than `unsigned char` is the correspondence between the two members of `union { T v; unsigned char r[sizeof(T)]; }`.  Object representations are implementation-defined.  For example, the two most common object representations for a four-byte `unsigned int` are

   - big-endian: `v == (r[0] << 24 | r[1] << 16 | r[2] << 8 | r[3])`
   - little-endian: `v == (r[3] << 24 | r[2] << 16 | r[1] << 8 | r[0])`

   These should be understood as mathematical equations, not C expressions: `v` and `r[n]` are elements of ℕ (with zero), not limited-precision machine numbers. C notation is used for equality, base-2 left shift, and bitwise or, but these are also meant to be mathematical operators in ℕ.  (I would use proper math notation if this site had MathJax enabled.)

   For signed integer types, the equations would include the rule for handling negative numbers, and for floating-point they would split the bytes up into sign, exponent, and mantissa bitfields and then reassemble them into an element of ℚ.

The example code you showed,

```
const int arr[5] = {0x1021, 0x8988, 0x706, 0x50, 0x22};
int *ptr = memchr(arr, 0x89, sizeof(arr));
```

is, assuming `int` and `int32_t` are the same type, and assuming little-endian object representations, and we don't care how negative numbers are represented because all the numbers in the array are positive, equivalent to

```
const uint8_t arr[20] = {
  0x21, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x88, 0x89, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x06, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x22, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};
int *ptr = memchr(arr, 0x89, sizeof(arr));
```

You can see that the value being searched for, 0x89, occurs at offset 5 from the start of this second array.

(Note: the type of `ptr` should be `uint8_t *`, not `int *`.  The pointer returned by `memchr` is not necessarily a valid pointer to `int` (nor anything else besides `unsigned char`).)

Answer (score -2):

Instead of asking this question you could easily find the answer yourself just by adding few lines of code. You need to do it yourself if you really want to learn programing.

```
int main(void)
{
  const int arr[5] = {0x1021, 0x8988, 0x706, 0x50, 0x22};
  int * ptr;
  unsigned char *ucp = arr;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
  {
      printf("Byte no: %02zu = 0x%02hhx, %s\n", i, ucp[i], ucp[i] == 0x89 ? " <<<----" : "");
  }
  
  ptr = memchr(arr, 0x89, sizeof(arr));
  printf("arr:%p ptr:%p diff = %zd\n", (void *)arr, (void *)ptr, (ptrdiff_t)ptr - (ptrdiff_t)arr);
}
```

and the output:

```
Byte no: 00 = 0x21, 
Byte no: 01 = 0x10, 
Byte no: 02 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 03 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 04 = 0x88, 
Byte no: 05 = 0x89,  <<<----
Byte no: 06 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 07 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 08 = 0x06, 
Byte no: 09 = 0x07, 
Byte no: 10 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 11 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 12 = 0x50, 
Byte no: 13 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 14 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 15 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 16 = 0x22, 
Byte no: 17 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 18 = 0x00, 
Byte no: 19 = 0x00, 
arr:0x7fffc2747900 ptr:0x7fffc2747905 diff = 5
```

I think that the answer is quite obvious now.